Can't fit big table (40 x 9) in Latex - Overleaf
Here is the code that I tried and for whatever reason the columns won't split correctly on mulitple pages. Please let me know how to fix this!

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lllllllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Topic} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Author} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Main Pupose} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Methods for Valuation} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Datasets} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Main limitation and Future Research Suggestion} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Valuation of Methods} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(Sustainable) Features} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Important Remarks} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{9}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Topic} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Author} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Main Pupose} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Methods for Valuation} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Datasets} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Main limitation and Future Research Suggestion} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Valuation of Methods} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(Sustainable) Features} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Important Remarks} \\ \hline
\endhead
%
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Papers from Scopus (SLR)} \\ \hline
S &
  Shaik et al. (2024) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Examine how critical technological factors of big data analytics contribute to \\ stakeholder satisfaction in SMEs through the mediation of environmental and economic sustainability\end{tabular} &
  Structural equation &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Data from 324 SMEs\\ \\ Questionnaire from 309 valid responses\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Limited sample size of SMEs \&  \\ More SMEs from different locations (not just USA, UK) \\ and directly obtaining secondary data from SMEs\end{tabular} &
   &
  Environmental and Economical &
   \\
IT &
  Thangeda et al. (2024) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Analyze customer retention strategies using an artificial neural network-based decision model \\ applied to real-life data from mobile service users in India\end{tabular} &
  Artificial neural network-based decision &
  311 mobile service users &
  Larger dataset &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Customer dissatisfaction/disloyalty/churn\\ Adaptability, Customer service, Connectivity, Skills of employees,\\ Advertisement, Reliability, Repurchase intention, Continuity in usage\end{tabular} &
   \\
IT &
  Baabdullah (2024) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigate the determinants influencing the intention to use AI applications \\ among non-adopters in the Saudi Arabian context, while also evaluating and \\ enhancing the predictive validity of the IAAAM\end{tabular} &
  AI acceptance-avoidance &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factors related to business organizations at the macro-level have not been\\ covered (readiness, infrastructure, and culture)\end{tabular} &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Performance expectancy, Facilitating conditions, Personal well-being concern,\\ Perceived threat, and Attitudes\end{tabular} &
   \\
IT &
  Armenia et al. (2024) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigate the extent and direction of convergence between AI and SD within the \\ business and management landscape\end{tabular} &
  Bibliometric analysis and Topic modeling &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sample restricted to Web of Science \&  \\ Include the conclusion sections of papers, along with abstracts\end{tabular} &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Supply chain, System dynamics, Ecological and socio-economic systems, \\ Transportation, Healthcare, Risk management, Innovation, Price control, Soft modeling\end{tabular} &
   \\
IT &
  Shankar et al. (2024) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigate the impact of AI frameworks for climate change competency on firm \\ performance and decision-making processes in the B2B market, with a focus on how \\ climate change competency can mitigate associated risks and contribute to \\ sustainable development goals\end{tabular} &
  Factor analysis and Structural equation &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}204 service managers \\ from B2B firms\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Results are not universal \& \\ Incorporating more explicit climate related\\ questions for a comprehensive analysis\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
   \\
IT &
  Sahoo et al. (2024) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigate how AI influence open innovation practices and subsequently \\ impact business performance in B2B organizations\end{tabular} &
  Structural equation &
  398 B2B multinational companies &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Focus on multinational B2B companies \& \\ focus upon exploring the impact of AI capabilities \\ and open innovation on different types of business\\ performance outcomes\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
   \\
- &
  Rammer et al. (2023) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Address the challenges associated with obtaining indicators on firm innovation \\ activities by exploring the potential of utilizing digital big data sources\end{tabular} &
   &
  Crunchbase database &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Biased information, limited coverage, lack of accuracy and consistency, \\ varying timeliness \&\\ More research is needed to identify and quantify such biases\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
   \\
IT &
  Curiskis et al. (2023) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ML framework for predicting CLV in the B2B SaaS setting, \\ addressing challenges related to nuanced customer relationships\end{tabular} &
  Hierarchical T-period model and Ensembled customer &
   &
   &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Customer revenue stream, Product license details, \\ Product feature usage information, and Account-level firmographic details\end{tabular} &
   \\
IT &
  Costa-Climent et al. (2023) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Theoretical understanding of the factors influencing value creation and capture \\ in start-ups utilizing ML technology, by exploring the relationship between \\ data network effects and business model theory\end{tabular} &
   &
  122 start-ups &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}start-ups that may decide not to raise funds from investors \\ do not appear in databases\end{tabular} &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Novelty, Useful, performance, Efficiency, Effort, \\ Complementarity, Explainability, Transparency\end{tabular} &
   \\
IT &
  Mikalef et al. (2023) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigate the impact of AI competencies on B2B marketing capabilities and \\ organizational performance\end{tabular} &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}155 survey responses \\ from European companies\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Choice of method only allows us to infer causality and assume that there\\ is a significant effect \& A qualitative approach with a smaller sample\end{tabular} &
  Test for mediation &
  Marketing information management/planning/implementation &
   \\
IT &
  Nie et al. (2022) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Develop a comprehensive framework for CLV estimation using real insurance \\ policy data, covering all aspects from data preparation to validation\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Frequency Recency monetary model, Probability model, Pareto/NBD, \\ Econometric model, Markov Chain Model\end{tabular} &
   &
  Used only five models &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Query-based and  \\ Recency-Frequency-Monetary\end{tabular} &
  Retention and Acquisition rates, Future cash flow &
   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Papers outside of SLR} \\ \hline
- &
  Damodaran (2012) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Explore the valuation of various financial assets and real assets, highlighting the \\ common principles and differences among valuation models\end{tabular} &
  DCF, Relative valuation, Asset-Based Valuation, Contingent Claim Valuation &
   &
  The book assumes relatively efficient markets, which may not always be the case in practice &
   &
  Traditional financial metrics &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The book emphasizes the importance of using multiple valuation methods to get a comprehensive view of a company's value. \\ Accurate valuation requires a deep understanding of the underlying assumptions and careful consideration of the inputs used in the models.\end{tabular} \\
- &
  Miciuła et al. (2020) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The significance of enterprise valuation in contemporary business transactions, presenting \\ a comprehensive overview of valuation methods and proposing the MDI-R concept to enhance \\ valuation accuracy and fairness\end{tabular} &
  Asset-Based, Income-Based, Mixed, Comparable Company, Unconventional &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The need for a tool that will solve the following problems that current business valuation methods are facing: freedom \\ of selection of input data, use of wide subjectivity in the common valuation procedure, subjectivity of selection \\ of valuation methods and internal parameters, lack of coherence in estimation of parameters, \\ lack of legal regulations and standards of valuation.\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}“Adjusted net assets valuation method is currently the best (objective and the closest to the model fair value) solution, which is confirmed by the \\ fact that it is the basis for all valuations in economic practice” “Business valuation methods should take into account as many components of the \\ company affecting its value as possible”\end{tabular} \\
- &
  Kim-Duc et al. (2024) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Develop formulae for earnings growth rates in business valuation models, addressing errors \\ introduced by cross-referencing between the reinvestment rate and return on invested capital\end{tabular} &
  Dividend discount, Flows-to-Equity, Capital cash flow, Cost of capital, Adjusted present value &
   &
   &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Earnings growth rates, Reinvestment rate, Returns on invested capital, \\ Future cash flows, Discount rate\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}“Errors in growth rates persist when the valuers cross-reference in different methods when calculating RIR and ROIC” “The correct formula for \\ estimating growth rates implies that reinvestment of capital is also the primary determinant, along with reinvestment rates and changes in ROIC“ \\ “A business valuation cannot have an accessible expected growth rate, a fixed change in ROIC, independent reinvestment timing, \\ and a fixed level of actual reinvestment. We call this fact the ‘impossible quaternity’”\end{tabular} \\
S &
  Koczar et al. (2023) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Integration of ESG factors into business valuation methodologies to inform decision-making \\ and enhance the management of business value within the framework of sustainable development\end{tabular} &
  CAPM &
   &
   &
   &
  ESG factors &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Mandelbaum factors:\\ • The validity of financial indicators, forecast revenue and profitability, as well as the business reputation of the company;\\ • The nature of the company, its history, position in the industry, and economic prospects;\\ • Reputational and professional qualities of the company's managers, as well as their fame in the industry.\end{tabular} \\
- &
  Tarczyński et al. (2020) &
  Examine the relationship between the value of the company, its fundamental strength and rates of return &
  Fundamental power index &
   &
  Extreme level of variables may disrupt the value of the company and its fundamental power (strength) association &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Book value, Liquidation value, Replacement value, \\ Fundamental value, Intrinsic value, Market value\end{tabular} &
   \\
IT &
  Enholm et al. (2021) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Conduct a systematic literature review to understand how organizations can effectively utilize \\ AI technologies to generate business value, while identifying key enablers, inhibitors, typologies, \\ and effects of AI adoption and use\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}NLP, Computer vision, Expert system, \\ Planning and scheduling, Speech synthesis systems\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
   &
  Ethical and Moral Aspects, Regulations, Environmental Pressure &
   \\
IT &
  Schoormann et al. (2023) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Explore how Information Systems research utilizes AI to promote sustainable development, \\ aiming to provide insights for informed investments and identify potential areas for future research\end{tabular} &
  ML, NLP, Computer vision, others &
  95 articles &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Neglected other perspectives (CS, environmental science), only focused on IS, neglected other research results such as purely \\ conceptual finding \& \\ Suggested RQ are: "What can we learn from well-researched fields to advance other SDGs? and "What are opportunities for \\ reusing and adapting available solutions to new situations?"\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}cross-validation, k-fold, leave-one-out cross-validation; \\ regarding measuring the ML model’s generalizability, \\ accuracy, precision, recall and F1-score is measured\end{tabular} &
  Economic, Ecological and Social &
   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Papers from Google Scholar} \\ \hline
- &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Saksonova et al. (2020)} &
  Comparing classical and advanced methodologies for business valuation &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Value Based Management, Economic Value Added, \\ Cash Value Added, Created Shareholder Value, \\ Cash Flow Return on Investment, Real Option Value\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adjusted book profit, Operating cash flow, capital expenditures,\\ Investment, economic life of\\ Investment, Company cash\\ flows, economic life of assets, cost of debt\end{tabular} &
   \\
S &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Rath (2021)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Explore the integration of sustainability into company valuation methods for SMEs, \\ emphasizing the importance of including qualitative aspects and intangible assets to accurately \\ reflect the impact of sustainable practices on business value\end{tabular} &
  CAPM &
  10 semi-structured interviews &
  Size of the sample is narrow \& Technique to include soft skills in the traditional valuation methods &
   &
  ESG factors &
   \\
IT &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sawant (2022)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Address two major issues in the BFSI sector—fraud detection and CLV calculation—by applying ML \\ models to publicly available data from the banking and insurance domains\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Support vector machine, Extreme Gradient boosting, Bernoulli Naive\\ Bayes, Decision tree, and Random Forest, Lasso Regression, Random Forest Regression,\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Kaggle (customers in the domain of banking\\ and insurance that contains the data related \\ to the demographic, financial, vehicle, \\ or policy-related information)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Very few numbers of research are found \&amp; A solution to other\\ problems and integrating it into the same system\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
   \\
IT &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Dai (2022)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Review the effectiveness of various machine learning models—Linear Regression, Support Vector Machine, \\ Random Forest, and Neural Network—in analyzing CLV for e-commerce companies, \\ identifying key influencing factors, and suggesting potential future research directions\end{tabular} &
  Linear Regression, Support Vector Machine, Random Forest, Neural Network &
  8099 samples &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}More datasets of CLV that can be analyze together \& Model fusion could be considered in future research to further\\ improve the accuracy and analyze important factors\end{tabular} &
   &
  Education, employment status, gender, income, location code, marital status, etc. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Random Forest performed best in predicting CLV, with significant features including monthly premium auto, \\ total claim amount, and coverage\end{tabular} \\
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Reddy et al. (2021)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Review the literature on CLV models and evaluate their effectiveness in assessing customer relationships, \\ with the system's performance measured using a mean absolute error of 1.23\%\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}hierarchical K-means, Ward's method, fuzzy C-means, \\ Bayesian organization, ANOVA, beta geometric/negative binomial regression model\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
   &
  Recency, Frequency, and monetary worth &
   \\
IT &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Kumar et al. (2023)} &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Models, Lasso and Ridge Regression, Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, Deep Learning, \\ K-means clustering, Cox Proportional-Hazards Model, Reinforcing Long-Term CLV \\ using Markov Decision Processes, Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average\end{tabular} &
  dataset of customer transactions and behaviors &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Businesses can make data-driven choices to improve their CRM and marketing strategies based on the\\ insights provided here.\end{tabular} &
   &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Using the Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average (ARIMA) model for the goal of forecasting the CLV is a technique \\ that is both successful and dependable;  it may demonstrate that some customer categories have a greater CLV or that \\ particular marketing channels are more successful at raising CLV\end{tabular} \\
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Tugui et al. (2020)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigate the ethical perspectives and challenges faced by authorized valuers in Romania, \\ particularly focusing on external pressures and the role of personal reputation and social responsibility \\ in ethical decision-making, through a nationwide survey of 558 respondents\end{tabular} &
   &
  Survey of 558 respondents &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It captures only the general aspects of the professional’s\\ position with reference to the importance of ethics in the activity of an authorized valuer, and possibly\\ only at the declarative level, the respondents’ opinion, ethics being a generally sensitive topic,\\ which could generate restraints and formal responses\end{tabular} &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ethics evaluation, Evaluation criteria, Advantages, Specific aspects, \\ Recommendations, Gender, Age, Tenure,\end{tabular} &
   \\
S &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Glavas (2023)} &
  Provide readers with methods to value businesses using financial models that factor in ESG data &
  DCF, Price-Earnings Ratios &
   &
  There is no universal agreement on the techniques for integrating ESG data into valuation multiples. &
   &
  ESG factors &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Integrating ESG factors into business valuation is crucial for reflecting true company value and aligning with investor\\ and consumer preferences. Both short-term and long-term impacts of ESG factors need careful consideration \\ to avoid mispricing and ensure accurate valuations\end{tabular} \\
IT &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Hubert et al. (2023)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Explore how AI algorithms can predict and optimize CLV by analyzing vast customer data \\ and employing machine learning models, thereby enhancing personalized marketing, targeted \\ retention strategies, and efficient resource allocation for businesses\end{tabular} &
  Regression Models, Neural Networks, Decision Trees &
   &
  AI algorithms aren’t infallible &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Purchase frequency, Average order\\ Value, transaction history, demographic information, behavioral data\end{tabular} &
  AI’s role in CLV – enhanced resource allocation, personalized retention strategies, maximize customer lifetime value \\
S &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Segarra-Moliner et al. (2023)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Analyze the relationship between ESG dimensions of corporate sustainability initiatives \\ and CLV across different segments of U.S. listed firms, using prediction-oriented modeling \\ to test hypotheses and evaluate the predictive validity of a partial least squares model\end{tabular} &
  PLS prediction-oriented segmentation, predictive validity (q2\_predict) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}547 U.S. listed firms from the Refinitiv Thomson \\ Reuters Eikon database \\ (262 tech firms and 285 industrial firms)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Dataset with firms only from US and it considers profit margins as free cash flow and net sales \& \\ We suggest a major study with more countries and industries\end{tabular} &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ESG factors, Corporate financial performance, Fuzzy set qualitative comparative analysis, \\ Return on assets, Tobin’s Q, Stock market return\end{tabular} &
   \\
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Bottazzi et al. (2023)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}A robust methodology for company market valuation that replaces traditional point estimates with a \\ probability distribution of fair values, enhancing the accuracy and predictive power of company valuations and market \\ factors through econometric modeling and historical data analysis\end{tabular} &
  Stochastic Discounted Cash Flow, Fama-MacBeth Regression Framework, Factor Models &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The study is primarily based on publicly traded U.S. companies, which may limit the generalizability \\ of the findings to other markets or private firms. \& Extend the application of the SDCF method to \\ different markets, including emerging economies and private firms, to test its robustness and generalizability.\end{tabular} &
   &
  Company Revenues, Balance Sheet Relations, Mispricing Indicator &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The study finds that the mispricing indicator, which is the difference between the market price and expected \\ fair value adjusted for volatility, has significant predictive power for future market returns.\end{tabular} \\
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Boeijink (2024)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigate the strategic and operational factors influencing the valuation of \\ telecommunications companies, particularly focusing on mobile network operators \\ and internet service providers, and to provide recommendations \\ for improving their valuation through qualitative analysis and expert insights\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}DCF, Comparable company analysis, \\ Shareholder value, Market multiples, Present discounted value, \\ Asset-based, (real) Options, Free Cash Flow to Firm and Free Cash Flow to Equity\end{tabular} &
   &
  Done only in the Netherlands &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enterprise value, EBITDA, cost of equity, cost of debt, revenue diversification, \\ cost management, capital structure, risk management, investment planning, and dividend policies\end{tabular} &
   \\
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Ernst (2023)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Identify the appropriate understanding and implementation of risk measures in simulation-based business \\ valuations, ensuring methodologically correct risk assessment to avoid valuation errors\end{tabular} &
  Monte Carlo simulation, CAPM &
   &
  Data availability is the main barrier &
   &
  EBIT, cash flow, &
   \\
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Wang et al. (2023)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Demonstrate the significance of the synergistic effect in mergers and acquisitions by \\ analyzing various organizational indicators and using \\ practical examples to highlight its impact on diversification and sales growth\end{tabular} &
  DCF &
   &
   &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}WACC, EBITDA, income tax, equity capital, debt capital, EBIT, D\&A, \\ Taxes, CAPEX, NWC, FCF, DFCF\end{tabular} &
   \\
S &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Iuras et al. (2023)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Potential correlations between ESG factors and business valuation by reviewing \\ key literature and conducting an empirical analysis of Romanian companies from 2020 to 2022, \\ highlighting the impact of ESG scores on profitability and market performance\end{tabular} &
  DCF, modified Ohlson model &
   &
   &
   &
  ESG factors, operating revenues, operating costs, capital expenditures, taxes, &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Out of two Romanian companies, the company with a higher ESG score has better general performance, \\ and is performing better on the market\end{tabular} \\
S &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Aydoğmuş et al. (2022)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigate the impact of ESG performance on firm value and profitability, using a large dataset to \\ determine the relationships between overall ESG scores and individual ESG components \\ with financial outcomes\end{tabular} &
   &
  1720 companies from 2013 to 2021 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The dynamics behind this link between ESG performance, firm value and profitability \\ could be interesting for future research\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF), Breusch-Pagan \\ Lagrange Multiplier test, Hausman test, \\ Pesaran CD test, Breusch-Godfrey/Wooldridge \\ test, Breusch-Pagan test\end{tabular} &
  ESG factors, Return on Assets (ROA), Tobin's Q &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}We find that ESG combined score (ESG\_CS) has a positive and highly significant relationship with the firm value. \\ Social (SOC) and Governance (GOV) have highly significant positive relationships with firm value as well. \\ However, Environment (ENV) has no relationship with firm value\end{tabular} \\
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Alshehhi et al. (2018)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Analyze the literature on the impact of corporate sustainability on financial performance, \\ identifying trends and issues that prevent a  conclusive consensus on the relationship\end{tabular} &
   &
  132 papers from top-tier journals are shortlisted &
  Further research is needed for countries of developing economies. &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Economic, Environmental, Social, Return on assets, Return on equity, return on investment (ROI), \\ and earning per share (EPS), Tobin’s Q, Price to Earning (P/E) Ratio, Market Valuation, Cash Flow\end{tabular} &
   \\
S &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yaghoub et al. (2022)} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Explore the impact of ESG scores on the value and financial performance of firms in the airline industry, \\ while also examining the moderating roles of firm size and age\end{tabular} &
  Panel data analysis &
  38 airlines worldwide for the period 2009 to 2019 &
  Additional research is required on means of minimizing the bias in measurement and empirical approaches &
  Breusch–Pagan’s multiplier test, Hausman test &
  ESG factors &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The moderating role of firm size in the relationship between ESG and dependent variables is significant. Firm age may also overlap \\ the association and influence the firm's strategic decisions related with sustainability initiatives, but, in general, \\ we did not find it to be a significant moderator\end{tabular}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}


Better stay away from these terrible online table generators. With all these annoying \multicolumn{1}... it is very hard to create a usable table which fits your page.

Please extend your sniplet into something others can copy and test as is.

I hope I extended the sniplet so that now you can test it as it is.

why is every cell a nested tabular? if you are using a generator that generated that, not using the generator would be the first improvement.

Yes indeed, I did use a generator.

Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

With that many column containing lengthy pieces of text I seriously doubt, you will be able to fit the table onto a page while keeping the font size legible.  would suggest to rethink the table design or go for a different format of presenting the infromation, instead.

Do you think it's possible to have it on multiple pages? Maybe a landscape format? @leandriis

Since your table contains many columns with lenghty texts in them, I suggest considering a redesign of the table. Here's a suggestion for such a redesign that might serve as a starting point:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlist{tabdescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[tabdescription]{noitemsep,wide,
                         topsep=0pt,
                         partopsep=0pt, 
                         nosep, 
                         before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, 
                         after=\end{minipage}}


\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{llX}
\caption{table caption}\\
\toprule
Topic & Author & Details \\ \midrule 
\endfirsthead
\caption{Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
Topic & Author & Details \\ \midrule 
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
S 
  & \makecell[lt]{Shaik et al.\\ (2024)} 
  & \begin{tabdescription}
      \item[Main Pupose] Examine how critical technological factors of big data analytics contribute to  stakeholder satisfaction in SMEs through the mediation of environmental and economic sustainability 
      \item[Methods for Valuation] Structural equation 
      \item[Datasets] Data from 324 SMEs Questionnaire from 309 valid responses 
      \item[Main limitation and Future Research Suggestion] Limited sample size of SMEs \& More SMEs from different locations (not just USA, UK)  and directly obtaining secondary data from SMEs 
      \item[Valuation of Methods] 
      \item[(Sustainable) Features] Environmental and Economical 
      \item[Important Remarks]~
    \end{tabdescription}
  \\
IT
  & \makecell[lt]{Thangeda et al.\\ (2024)}
  & \begin{tabdescription}
      \item[Main Pupose] Analyze customer retention strategies using an artificial neural network-based decision model applied to real-life data from mobile service users in India
      \item[Methods for Valuation] Artificial neural network-based decision
      \item[Datasets]  311 mobile service users 
      \item[Main limitation and Future Research Suggestion] Larger dataset  
      \item[Valuation of Methods] 
      \item[(Sustainable) Features] Customer dissatisfaction/disloyalty/churn Adaptability, Customer service, Connectivity, Skills of employees, Advertisement, Reliability, Repurchase intention, Continuity in usage 
      \item[Important Remarks]~
    \end{tabdescription} 
  \\
IT 
  & \makecell[lt]{Baabdullah\\ (2024)}
  & \begin{tabdescription}
      \item[Main Pupose] Investigate the determinants influencing the intention to use AI applications  among non-adopters in the Saudi Arabian context, while also evaluating and  enhancing the predictive validity of the IAAAM
      \item[Methods for Valuation]  AI acceptance-avoidance
      \item[Datasets]  
      \item[Main limitation and Future Research Suggestion] Factors related to business organizations at the macro-level have not been covered (readiness, infrastructure, and culture) 
      \item[Valuation of Methods] 
      \item[(Sustainable) Features] Performance expectancy, Facilitating conditions, Personal well-being concern, Perceived threat, and Attitudes
      \item[Important Remarks]~
    \end{tabdescription}   
  \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}


  & \begin{tabdescription}
      \item[Main Pupose] 
      \item[Methods for Valuation] 
      \item[Datasets]  
      \item[Main limitation and Future Research Suggestion] 
      \item[Valuation of Methods] 
      \item[(Sustainable) Features] 
      \item[Important Remarks]~
    \end{tabdescription} 


Thank you a lot for your help!
